# Adding a Smarty variable with total value of the sum of three combo box

Tags: php, jquery, combobox, smarty

I have this code for add (sume up) three combo values and I want to sume up the val "precioinicial" from smarty variable with the result (resultado) But I don't know how to do it. Any help? Thank you very much.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('#form1').change(function() {
           var obj = {};
           var string = '';
           var precioinicial  = "{$productes_precio}";
           var sum  = 0;
           // Grupo 1
           if ($("select option[name=embroider]").is(':checked')) {
              var n1 = $("select option[name=embroider]:checked").val();
              sum += parseFloat(n1);
           }
            // Grupo 2
           if ($("select option[name=sole]").is(':checked')) {
              var n1 = $("select option[name=sole]:checked").val();
              sum  += parseFloat(n1);
           }
          // Grupo 3
           if ($("select option[name=taps]").is(':checked')) {
              var n1 = $("select option[name=taps]:checked").val();
              sum += parseFloat(n1);
           }
           $('#resultado').val(sum);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify whether the code is in a .js file or in a template processed by smarty. If it's the first case, you should at least declare precioinicial in some place of the template file (probably the head), i.e.

```
<html>
  <head>
  ...
    <script>
       var precioinicial  = "{$productes_precio}";
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  ...
```

then in you script you just have to use the variable and assign it to sum:

```
$('#form1').change(function() {
           var obj = {};
           var string = '';
           var sum  = parseFloat(precioinicial);
```

If the rest of your code is correct, it should work as expected.

Comment: Yes, the smarty variable is informed correctly.[EDIT] your solution works fine. It was parseFloat Very Very Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted is Javascript. As such it executes on the client. Smarty however is executed on the server. From your question I would say that you have an architecture issue at hand.

If you really want to pass the value to smarty, you'll have to do it via Ajax (although this then begs the question of why you're doing that in the first place, unless you want to pass Smarty-generated content back in your Ajax response).

Comment: Thank you. The smarty value is not the problem. It is reported correctly. The solution was parsefloat